# Zipkin Instrumentation for socket based app

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, zipkin

We have a socket based web app we currently developing using feathersJS, and we are currently leaning on using zipkin for performance tracking, but it seems that there's no instrumentation yet for socket based app, anyone have implemented Zipkin on socket based webapps? or any alternatives  you recommend? Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding Zipkin's tracing is basically for HTTP based request/response communication. Socket is used frequently for streaming where the source/server just streams and the sink/client just listens to some port. Therefore, Zipkin is particular not useful for tracing in this model of communication where the request/response propagation does not necessarily exists as client directly does need to know about the server or communicate directly.